# Is it haram to say 'holy crap' or 'holy cow' in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, sin

I sometimes say holy cow or crap whenever something shocking happens, I used this words because these words are used instead of a swear word as this wouldn't be considered swearing? But I wanna know is this still haram?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's kufr akhi, from what I've seen which is very minimal, if it's not meant it's minor kufr

Answer (score 0):

Assim Al Hakeem covered this topic on youtube you can watch.He said saying words like this are Kufr

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,
You should always try your best not to curse or use bad language. Yes, these words are not as bad as some other curse words, but they still have a negative connotation. Remember that Islam teaches us to use kind words and to speak eloquently. If you use them accidentally, of course, we are also taught that Allah (swt) forgives. However, if you try to stop using these words, iA you will gain even more reward because you are doing it for the sake of Allah (swt). Hope that helps!
***Remember that Muslims should neither curse each other as narrated Samurah Ibn Jundub (RA) that Allah’s Messenger (SAW) said: “Do not curse one another, invoking the curse of Allah or Wrath of Allah or the fire of Hell” (Tirmidhi). The act of cursing is such that one who does it can himself become a recipient of it.
Best,
-MuslimGap